# Want to Understand which VISA we have to apply

Tags: uk

I am at UK on work permit for 88 days, i want to invite my wife and kid from India to spend 2 weeks in UK to see all historical places here, which VISA i have to opt for them.

Comment: All VISA cards issued by your favorite financial institution ought to be accepted in the UK; otherwise they shouldn't carry the logo. (Note that your family may also need _visas_ in order to be allowed to enter the country, but that is a different matter).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends on the nationality of your wife and child. The easiest way to answer this question is to go to [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa). For the purpose of visit, you would select "Tourism, including visiting friends or family".

Comment: HI Greg, Thanks for coming back, we need VISA definitely as they have to travel from India. So please suggest me.

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can add. [You'll need a visa to come to the UK.](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/tourism)

Comment: The linked website walks you through what you might need.